# having problems installing ubuntu comset failed errno 16

Tags: system-installation, 14.10

I hope you can Help Having a problem installing kubuntu/ubuntu 14.10 on to a older computer without secure boot, (comset failed errno 16), I can how ever install 12.10 as it doesn’t need secure boot

Answer (score 0):

1. prepare a 2GB or 4GB USB flash, UltraISO and Ubuntu 14.10 ISO
2. Use UltraISO to open the ISO and write the ISO document to flash.

There is one point that you'd better use HDD form to write the ISO rather than HDD+. Because many 
old boards do not support HDD+.